# Calculating percentages based on a few columns in a subgroup

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table (let's call it `Table A`) like this:

```
ID        Device        Clicks
1         A             10
1         B             10
2         A             1
2         C             19
```

I would like to build a table (let's call it `Table B`) from `A` above like this:

```
ID        Device        Clicks        Percentage
1         A             10            50
1         B             10            50
2         A             1             5
2         C             19            95
```

Again from `Table B`, I'd like to derive `Table C` where the `Updated Device` column for each of the `ID` will carry the name from the `Device` column only if the `Percentage` is >=95%. If the percentage split between `Devices` for each `ID` is anything else, we'll simply set `UpdatedDevice` to `Others`.  For example, using the data in `Table B`, we'll get a `Table C` like below:

```
ID        Device        Clicks        Percentage    UpdatedDevice
1         A             10            50            Others
1         B             10            50            Others
2         A             1             5             C
2         C             19            95            C
```

I am wondering if there's a way to do this with advanced SQL windowing/analytical functions in one shot instead of generating intermediate tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select 
    Id
  , Device
  , Clicks
  , Percentage 
  , UpdatedDevice = isnull(max(UpdatedDevice) over (partition by Id),'Others')
from (
  select *
    , Percentage = convert(int,(clicks / sum(clicks+.0) over (partition by Id))*100)
    , UpdatedDevice = case 
        when (clicks / sum(clicks+.0) over (partition by Id)) >= .95
          then Device
        end
  from t
) as cte
```

test setup: http://rextester.com/XKBNO39353

returns:

```
+----+--------+--------+------------+---------------+
| Id | Device | Clicks | Percentage | UpdatedDevice |
+----+--------+--------+------------+---------------+
|  1 | A      |     10 | 50         | Others        |
|  1 | B      |     10 | 50         | Others        |
|  2 | A      |      1 | 5          | C             |
|  2 | C      |     19 | 95         | C             |
+----+--------+--------+------------+---------------+
```

Comment: Thank you so much for providing a very easy to understand query with correct solution!

Answer (score 1):

Just for kicks, you can do this without a subquery:

```
select t.*,
       clicks * 1.0 / sum(clicks) over (partition by id) as ratio,  -- you an convert to a percentage
       (case when max(clicks) over (partition by id) >= 0.95 * sum(clicks) over (partition by device)
             then first_value(device) over (partition by id order by clicks desc)
             else 'Others'
        end) as UpdatedDevice             
from t;
```

The key idea for calculating `UpdatedDevice` is that the maximum would be the device that satisfies the 95% rule.  And `first_value()` of course.

Comment: Thank you! It is cool to learn a solution for my case without any subquery. :)